# Объекты или двумерные массивы

Tags: массивы, объекты

Что лучше использовать двумерный массив или объект? 
В двумерном массиве я могу сразу обратиться к нужной мне ячейке, в объекте свойства придется проходить циклом for...of. Что займет больше времени как я понимаю, однако двумерные массивы занимают больше памяти (из примера сохранения двумерного массива в MongoDB). Помогите найти золотую середину.

Comment: О каком языке речь?

Comment: Речь идет о Javascript

Answer (score 0):

В JavaScript все есть объект, массив можно использовать как объект, и наоборот, используя объект или массив, они гарантировано подадутся очистки(если речь о движке V8), но надо понимать что все для своих задач. Объект как сама структура, в Js чаще используется как список/хеш, массив именно как массив, но речь идёт о двухмерном массиве, как вы собираетесь делать «двух мерный объект» я не знаю. По поводу перебора, в JavaScript есть множество методов перебора объектов(массив тоже объекты), будь то for in, foreaxh, map, for, while, у массивов, и объектов они одинаковые, если вам прийдется перебегать массив, переберись вы его будете также как и объект. Но в конце концов, что лучше, решать вам.

А ещё я не очень понял, в массиве вы сможете обратится так

```
arr[0][2]
```

А в объекте вам обаятельно перебирать? А вот так обратится нельзя?

```
obj.key
```

Comment: Суть в том, что мне нужно извлечь из MongoDB координату x и y. Я могу хранить их в бд в двумерном массиве `arr[12][9] // и получить объект {name : Jhon}`. Либо же я могу хранить объект  `obj = {x : 12, y : 9, name : Jhon } // тогда, чтобы найти нужную мне координату придется обойти весь массив объектов полученных из бд циклом for...of и сравнить их свойства.` Двумерный массив занимает больше памяти в бд чем массив объектов полученных при запросе, однако с его помощью я могу выбирать информацию сразу не проходя все полученные объекты циклом for...of. Надеюсь вы меня поняли.